# Not able to access rails app on port 3001

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, port, webrick

I am trying to run rails app on different port (3001) using "rails s -p 3001"
Though the server gets started perfectly, but i am still not not able to access it. 
The same works perfectly fine on default port of 3000.

The machine which is being used is ubuntu 10.04 instance on aws.

Any help/suggestions will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rules for the security group on which you are running your instance at AWS. See if you enable port 3001.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open that port first (firewall is restrictive by default).

```
ec2-authorize SECURITY_GROUP_NAME_HERE -p 3001
```